# Implementation of AOP in Spring Framework MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I am trying to implement a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) API with [Spring MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Model-view-controller_framework). And my coding messed up while using `AOP Aspect` for my application. I need to check an `authToken` in every request coming for the source, so that I can give authorization and also I need it for logging.

In my code I have several `custom exception classes` inherited from another main `customized exception class` which is extented from Exception. When a custom exception is thrown, I need that just expected method waiting for exception works in my Aspect class so that I can return an appropriate error JSON response.

However, in my code both methods waiting for an exception work, and I wonder whether I have written my exception classes in a correct way or not. One more thing, I don't know how to tell that my aspect class does not to work for some actions which I define.

**Here is my code:**

```
@Aspect
public class SowLoggerAOP {

    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SowLoggerAOP");
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Resource(name = "personService")
    private PersonService personService;

    @Pointcut("execution(* sow.webservice.controllers..*.*(..))")
    private void selectAll(){}

    @Before("execution( * sow.webservice.controllers.PersonController.*(..))")
    public void logBeforeReq(JoinPoint jp) throws Exception{
        String personId = request.getParameter(Consts.AUTH_TOKEN);
        if (personService.isUserValid(personId)) {
            logger.debug("Spring AOP! Before invocation SUCCESFULL!!!: ");
        }
        else {
            logger.error("Person not found for the " + Consts.AUTH_TOKEN + " : " + personId);
            throw new PersonNotFoundException(
                "Person not found for the " + Consts.AUTH_TOKEN + " : " + personId,
                ErrorCodes.PERSON_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "selectAll()", throwing = "sowEx")
    public SowResult throwingSowException(SowCustomException sowEx){
        int errorCode = ErrorCodes.GENERAL_SYSTEM_ERROR;
        if(sowEx.getErrorCode() != 0)
            errorCode = sowEx.getErrorCode();
        SowResult result = new SowResult(Consts.SOW_RESULT_ERROR,
                                         errorCode,
                                         sowEx.getMessage(),
                                         "islem hata almistir!!");

        System.out.println("There has been an exception: " + sowEx.toString());
        return result;
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "selectAll()", throwing = "ex")
    public void throwingJavaException(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("JAVA EXCEPTION IS THROWN :");
    }
}

public class SowCustomException extends Exception{

    private int errorCode;

    public SowCustomException(){
        super();
    }

    public SowCustomException(String errMsg){
        super(errMsg);
    }
    public SowCustomException(String errMsg, int errorCode){
        super(errMsg);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public SowCustomException(int errorCode){
        super();
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }
    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
}
public class PersonNotFoundException extends SowCustomException{

    public PersonNotFoundException(){
        super();
    }

    public PersonNotFoundException(String errMsg){
        super(errMsg);
    }

    public PersonNotFoundException(String errMsg, int errorCode){
        super(errMsg);
        super.setErrorCode(errorCode);
    }

    public PersonNotFoundException(int errorCode){
        super();
        super.setErrorCode(errorCode);
    }
}
```

**Expected JSON must be created from that class:**

```
public class SowResult {

    public int resultCode; // 1- Succesfull, 0- Fail
    public int errorCode;
    public String errorString;
    public String message;
    public Date date;
    public SowResult(int resultCode, int errorCode, String errorString,
            String message) {
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        this.errorCode = errorCode; // 0 - No Error
        this.errorString = errorString;
        this.message = message;
        this.date = new Date();
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what is or isn't working with this code

Comment: sorry! I added some extra info about what I need here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Spring's AOP stack ignores any return value from an `@AfterThrowing` advice method. It just executes it and then continues by throwing the originally thrown exception.

You might want to use an `@Around` advice, wrap the `proceed` call in a `try-catch` block, generate your `SowResult` and return it.

Comment: I did what you said. what should I return from method implementing @Around annotation? Because it return this exception now:
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/sow] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: shoponway.webservice.common.SowResult cannot be cast to java.util.List] with root cause

Comment: @Emilla AOP is not magic. If your method is meant to return a `List` (and that's what you're assigning the invocation to) then that's what your method should return (even if it's through AOP reflection). You're trying to make it return a `SowResult`.

Comment: Yes I got it. Then spring doesn't offer me a solution here as I understand. Because I may have many actions and some of them may return List object, some return object and some return even just a string. So how can I customize a method which can handle my exception and return an appropriate error json(in my situation SowResult obj).
Maybe I am thinking wrongly, then please clarify me!

Comment: @Emilla Where do you expect that `SowResult` to go? Can't you just write an `@ExceptionHandler`?

Comment: Let me explain what I need briefly. I have several custom exception which has an attribute named errorCode, and I have error messages in my properties files matching these error codes. So, if a custom exception is thrown I need to catch it and return error code with error message in json format. Spring does that with @RequestBody for me. And If an unexpected exception is thrown I again need to catch it and return a general system error with SowResult again.

Comment: @Emilla Look into `@ExceptionHandler`. You can implement one for each (or all) your custom exceptions and make it return JSON just like a controller's `@RequestMapping` methods.

Comment: Yes I did what you said and it worked. However if error thrown from my AOP class(which I am using to check authToken coming from every request) @ExceptionHandler can not get it. It catches only exception thrown from my controller itself.

Comment: @Emilla That shouldn't be the case. The advice will be applied when the handler method is invoked by the `DispatcherServlet` stack. If an exception is thrown it will be delegated to the `@ExceptionHandler`. I would ask you to provide more details or ask a new question (with all the details).

Answer (score 1):

As Sotirios Delimanolis said, if you want to return something after intercepting a method that throws an exception, you should use `@Around`. Something like this (I am trusting that your pointcut is correct):

```
@Around("selectAll()")
   public Object handleException(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
      int errorCode = ErrorCodes.GENERAL_SYSTEM_ERROR;
      if(sowEx.getErrorCode() != 0)
         errorCode = sowEx.getErrorCode();
      SowResult retVal = null;

      try {
         retVal = (SowResult) pjp.proceed();
      } catch (RequestValidationException sowEx) {
         //now return the error response
         return new SowResult(Consts.SOW_RESULT_ERROR,
                                     errorCode,
                                     sowEx.getMessage(),
                                     "islem hata almistir!!");
      }

  return retVal;
}
```